# How to avoid copying specific file format using cp command

Tags: bash, shell

I am using cp command in ma bash script

```
cp /source/* /destination
```

I just want to avoid copying all .txt file from my source to destination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If extended globulation is enabled, you can match al files except txt ones:

```
cp /source/!(*.txt) /destination
```

`*.txt` matches all txt files. The `!(...)` tells it to match everything except what's in the `...` part.

Comment: bash: !: event not found

Comment: Try after `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Its not working while I am writing into the script, any idea?

Comment: did you take Kamil's advice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this in copy but the rsync command has this ability. Try

rsync -av /source/* /destination --exclude "*txt".

See https://www.howtogeek.com/168009/how-to-exclude-files-from-rsync/ for some more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname "*.txt" \) -print0 | xargs -0 cp {} /destination
```

The -print0 and -0 are needed to handle files that could have spaces in the name.